# Inheritance with generics and overloading a method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, generic-constraints

I have a class with the following method:

```
public abstract class TypedMessage<T>{

    public TypedMessage<T> setBody(byte[] body) {
        this.body = body;
        return this;
    }
```

In a subclass of `TypedMessage`, I want to overload this method. So I do the following:

```
public class ThriftMessage<T extends TBase> extends TypedMessage<T>{

    public TypedMessage<T> setBody(T body) {
        byte[] data = ThriftMessageUtils.messageBodyToByteArray(body);
        this.body = data;
        return this;
    }
```

Note the constraint on the `T` generic. That it must extend `TBase`. This all compiles fine. Now when I go to use it in a class declared like this:

```
public abstract class CQSTask<CQSEvent extends TBase>{

    protected void sendCQS(CQSEvent cqsEvent) throws Exception{
        TypedMessage<CQSEvent> message = 
            new ThriftMessage<CQSEvent>(getCQSEventClass())
                .setBody(cqsEvent) //<---Compile error
```

The `setBody()` throws a compile error. It is trying to reference the:

```
public TypedMessage<T> setBody(byte[] body)
```

version of the method in `TypedMessage` and not the overloaded version in `ThriftMessage`.

This is confusing because in my class where I declare the generic param `CQSEvent` I have the constraint that it extends `TBase` as well. Can anyone help me understand why its not trying to reference the overloaded version?

Update:

Here is the error message

```
error: incompatible types: CQSEvent cannot be converted to byte[]
            .setBody(cqsEvent);
                     ^
```

where CQSEvent is a type-variable:
    CQSEvent extends TBase declared in class CQSTask

Comment: Read the error message. It doesn't try to use the method with a byte array as argument. It complains that your setBody() method returns a TypesMessage<CQSEvent>, which can thus not be assigned to a variable of type ThriftMessage<CQSEvent> without a cast. If you remove this assignment, or add a cast, or declare the message variable as TypedMessage<CQSEvent>, it compiles fine.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the reply. I have updated the code to what you suggested. In my real code, that is actually what I have. For this example I was trying to simplify things. But the error message does reference the byte[] version. Ive posted the compile error.

Comment: When I try to reporduce, I see that it is calling the setBody in ThriftMessage; I don't have any compile issues. It might be that you're passing in`getCQSEventClass()` as a parameter for the constructor, when you haven't declared a constructor.

Comment: Can you confirm that your method in `ThriftMessageUtils` takes in a `T extends TBase`?

Comment: Post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem. With what you posted, as I said, I can't reproduce it.